# Nokogiri for selecting text and html between between unique sets of tags

Tags: ruby, xpath, css-selectors, nokogiri

I am trying to use Nokogiri to extract the text in-between two unique sets of tags.

What is the best way to get the text within the p-tag in between `<h2 class="point">The problem</h2>` and `<h2 class="point">The solution</h2>`, and then all of the HTML between `<h2 class="point">The solution</h2>` and `<div class="frame box sketh">`?

Sample of the full html:

```
<h2 class="point">The problem</h2>
<p>TEXT I WANT </p>
<h2 class="point">The solution</h2>
HTML I WANT with it's own set of tags (but never an <h2> or <div>)
<div class="frame box sketh"><img src="URL for Image I want later" alt="" /></div>
```

Thank you!

Comment: I should add, the "HTML I want with it's own set of tags" is free text which might also contain html tags (except it just so happens it won't contain a div or h2). I don't like the idea of selecting h2 tags by the order they appear on the page, as the names within the h2 tags are unique and more appropriate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri.HTML(DATA)
doc.search('//h2/following-sibling::node()[name() != "h2" and name() != "div" and text() != "\n"]').each do |block|
  p block.text
end

__END__
<h2 class="point">The problem</h2>
<p>TEXT I WANT</p>
<h2 class="point">The solution</h2>
<div>dont capture this</div>
<span>HTML I WANT with it's <p>own set <b>of</b> tags</p></span>
<div class="frame box sketh"><img src="URL for Image I want later" alt="" /></div>
```

Output:

```
"TEXT I WANT"
"HTML I WANT with it's own set of tags"
```

This XPath selects all following sibling nodes of `h2` which is not a `h2`, `div` or contains nothing but the string `"\n"`.

Comment: you should limit your xpath till next h2 other wise it will get all nodes data that are not h2 or div

Comment: @akhterwahab I should add, the "HTML I want with it's own set of tags" is free text which might also contain html tags (except it just so happens it won't contain a div or h2). I don't like the idea of selecting h2 tags by the order they appear on the page, as the names within the h2 tags are unique and more appropriate to ensure we capture the right sections. Are there any other options? Thank you!

Comment: I'm not sure I follow, it'll always select by the order they appear on the page. When you say the names within the h2 tags are specific, I assume you mean text? In which case you can do `//h2[text()="The Problem"]` is that what you mean?

Comment: @injekt Thank you! So for the first it's `//h2[text()="The Problem"]/following-sibling::p[./following-sibling::h2[text()="The Solution"]]/text()`.

Comment: @injekt For the second, how would I modify the doc.search to copy all the text/html (it's preferable to maintain the html tags for this series of results) between `<h2 class="point">The solution</h2>` and `<div class="frame box sketh">`?

Comment: @Doug how about `//h2[.='The solution']/following-sibling::node()[1 = count(preceding-sibling::div[1] | ../h2[.='The solution'])]`

Answer (score 1):

here is how you can get p tags text between two h2 that contains class **point**

```
//h2[@class="point"][1]/following-sibling::p[./following-sibling::h2[@class="point"]]/text()
```

for **second** one you should explore [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/) , and take first one as example and do it.

Comment: @injekt his question is clear 
"What is the best way to get the text within the p-tag in between <h2 class="point">The problem</h2> and <h2 class="point">The solution</h2>"

and this is satisfying his need.

Comment: Sorry yeah I removed my comment hoping you wouldn't see it as it was misleading, I thought you were also talking about his second question (then I saw your comment on that, too).