# Searching for contents between two specified tags

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, css-selectors, nokogiri

I installed Nokogiri into a Rails project and it can currently run "[Nokogiri HTML Parser Example](http://runnable.com/UjQ4mOziD5kVAAFD/nokogiri-html-parser-example-for-ruby-on-rails)" with no issues.

I'm trying to create a Rails project that will parse a movie script from [IMDB](http://www.imsdb.com), conduct a word count, then display the most occurring words from that section. I've identified that the scripts are kept in a "table":

```
<table width=100% border=0 cellpadding=5 class=scrtext><tr><td class=scrtext><pre><html><head></head><body>

<b>PERSON1</b>
  They say some dialogue
<b>PERSON2</b>
  They say some more

</pre></table>
```

I would like to exclude the text within the `<b>/<b>` brackets as well.

I've been setting this up like the example above in the controller, and have gotten as far as taking in the URL:

```
#Save as a temp. file
tmp_file = open('http://www.imsdb.com/scripts/Authors-Anonymous.html')

#Parse the temp. file
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(tmp_file)
```

I'm having difficulty understanding how to set the CSS constraints to grab this table. I understand that it's between those `<pre>/<pre>` tags, and I've followed a number of tutorials for this but I still don't understand how to set up those constraints.

I feel that the code following this should be something like this, but I'm not awfully sure:

```
 doc.search("//pre")
```

How do I set up Nokogiri's CSS constraints to pull the content between two tags such as `<pre></pre>`, and then filter out irrelevant tags such as `<b></b>` that will occur within the output?

Comment: you can use the `css` method selector: `doc.css('pre b')` which will get every `<b>` tag(s) inside every `<pre>` tag(s)

Comment: Also as an addition (because I couldn't post more links), I've been looking at tutorials on the Nokogiri website (http://www.nokogiri.org/tutorials/searching_a_xml_html_document.html#basic_searching) and various StackOverflow questions (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12478272/nokogiri-for-selecting-text-and-html-between-between-unique-sets-of-tags), but I'm still quite confused by setting this up.

Comment: Welcome - you should post your answer in the answer section rather than the question. There is also no need to mark the question as solved, as accepting an answer does just that.

Comment: But only post your answer *if* it is to be your selected answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might not be the most elegant solution but it did the trick for me.

In the controller, I defined the following:`

```
  def index
    page = [THE_URL]
    doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(page))
    @content = doc.css('b').remove
    @content = doc.css('pre')
    puts @content
  end
```

and then in the View;

```
  <%=@content %>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `css` method selector: `doc.css('pre b')` which will get every `<b>` tag(s) inside every `<pre>` tag(s):

```
doc.css('pre b').each do |b_tag|
  # b_tag will be a String containg like `<b>this text is bold</b>`
end
```

Comment: This, along with the most straight forward example ever (http://www.ytutorial.com/tutorials/21-simple-nokogiri-tutorial-for-web-scraping-in-rails) helped me get to my answer. Thanks! :)